# How to use GData in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, gdata-api

I have used this [GData](https://github.com/google/gdata-objectivec-client) and the [tutorial](http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/) ...But every time I missed something and lost...I am working on sdk 4.0.

Here is the error page which occurs when I follow all steps
[image]

---

[edit] Now error down to 4

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Step 1**

The first step, is to head on over to the Google Code website for the Objective-C Client, download and extract the zip file source code. Alternatively, you can get the latest and greatest version via Git using:

```
git clone https://github.com/google/gdata-objectivec-client
```

If you downloaded the zip file from the website, you’ll have version 1.7.0.

**Step 2**

Open up the GData Xcode Project from your downloaded folder as well as your iPhone App Xcode project.

**Step 3**

Drag over the GData Sources Folder from the GData project to your iPhone App project and add it as reference [don't check the box for Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed).] You do not need to copy over all the files into your project. You can, but it’s not required.

**Step 4**

Open up the build settings for your iPhone App project. Located and set the following settings.
            * Header Search Paths: /usr/include/libxml2 ../gdata-objectivec-client-1.9.1/Source
    * Other Linker Flags: -lxml2, -ObjC

For the Debug build configuration only, add the Other C Flags setting so that the library’s debug-only code is included:

```
Other C Flags: -DDEBUG=1
```

**Step 5**

Now be sure that the downloaded source code is in the same directory in which your actual  Code Folder is.

**Step 6**
Make sure I've the frameworks "SystemConfiguration.FrameWork" and "Security.FrameWork" added to your project.

Hope it helps..These are the steps for GData integration

Comment: i have got 16 errors___i have next version gdata-objectivec-client-1.11.0..........i lost in step 4

Comment: so instead of gdata-objectivec-client-1.9.1  use gdata-objectivec-client-1.11.0

Comment: @Swastik -- i lost in step 4 getting 16 errors.....Look what i did.... 1--Header Search Paths: /usr/include/libxml2
2---Other Linker Flags: -lxml2 and -ObjC(i added both)
3--for debug settings i used user define settings named OtherCFlags and give value=-DDEBUG

Comment: @Swastik  -- after that when it did not work i used ***Header Search Paths: /usr/include/libxml2 ../gdata-objectivec-client-1.11.0/Source 
but no affect.....both projects are in Documents folder...

Comment: can you please provide some errors that you are getting

Comment: @Swastik i have edited my question to help me

Comment: add security.framework.It must work now

Comment: @Swastik----+1 for your answer i have edited my question please help....

Comment: @Swastik - can you come on skype? please

Comment: @Kumar I am bit busy now.I think you must  clean all targets, empty caches , then run

Comment: @Swastik   i did but no success

Comment: The last 4 errors comes from the SystemConfiguration.FrameWork that you have to add too.

Comment: hi guys! earlier i used XCode 3, but now i have XCode 4 and i don't understand how to drag item with gdata progect in my project. I make cross-references project. I have read through some lessons and there is shown that is necessary to create for the beginning from the gdata-project working space and then to add to it the project. tnx

Comment: I don't think this URL works..I can't find any API there :(

Comment: Hi, I am using xcode 6 and Xcode 7 and its displaying so much file missing and errors. Please can any one suggest, how I resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The error in the screenshot is that the system's Security.framework framework is not linked to the application, but the GData OAuth sign-in controller (which requires Security.framework) is linked into the app.

Either add Security.framework to your application target, or remove the OAuth source files.  This is mentioned at https://github.com/google/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary

Comment: I had suggested him the same.Please have a look at the comments we both exchanged.