# Problem with integrating GDATA in iPhone simulator using Xcode 4.0

Tags: iphone, gdata-api

I'm following the following steps to add GData to my project.

Reference from [I'm following this Tutorial](https://github.com/google/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary#linking-to-the-iphone-static-library)

1. Downloaded the source file from svn checkout **http://gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ gdata-objectivec-client-read-only** through terminal.
2. Dragged the source folder from the downloaded file into my xCode project.
3. Changed following build settings
            C Language Dialect: C99 [-std=c99] (Both for Debug and Release)
            Other C Flags: -DDEBUG=1  (Only for Debug)
            Header Search Paths: /usr/include/libxml2 (Both for Debug and Release)
            Other Linker Flags: -lxml2  (Both for Debug and Release)

But I'm getting some error when I build the code.

```
Error 1:  /Users/rajesh/Desktop/GooDataContacts/../../gdata-objectivec-client-read-only/Source/HTTPFetcher/Tests/GTMGatherInputStreamTest.m:16:40: error: SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h: No such file or directory

Error 2:  /Users/rajesh/Desktop/GooDataContacts/../../gdata-objectivec-client-read-only/Source/HTTPFetcher/Tests/GTMGatherInputStreamTest.m:21: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'SenTestCase', superclass of 'GTMGatherInputStreamTest'

Error 3:  file://localhost/Users/rajesh/gdata-objectivec-client-read-only/Source/HTTPFetcher/Tests/GTMGatherInputStreamTest.m: error: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h' file not found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GData in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543582/how-to-use-gdata-in-ios)