# How to import the Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C using Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, google-api, xcode4.2

The library is here.
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

I want to use the SDK with ARC mode enabled.
But somehow I can't find the correct way to import the SDK.
Is there any step-by-step tutorial?
Thanks!

I've tried the answer from [How to use GData in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543582/how-to-use-gdata-in-iphone). But it does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library documentation discusses ARC use [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary#ARC_Compatibility).

When compiling the library as a static lib or a framework, no special steps must be taken for ARC compatibility.

If compiling the library source files directly into the target of a project that has ARC enabled, then ARC must be disabled for the files of the library by using the compiler flag -fno-objc-arc