# How to get the photos from Picasa for my iphone app and how to integrate?

Tags: ios

How to integrate [picasa](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/) on a project to get the photos to my iphone app?

Comment: "This API is being [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/deprecation) and will be turned down in January 2019. Migrate to [Google Photos Library API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/developers_guide_migration) as soon as possible to avoid disruptions to your application."

Answer (score 0):

These link may help you

[How to use GData in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543582/how-to-use-gdata-in-iphone)

there are some GData objects are available (Google data APIs)

Each of the following Google services provides a Google Data API supported by this library:

--Google Analytics (superseded by a JSON API)

--Blogger

--Book Search (superseded by a JSON API)

--Calendar (superseded by a JSON API)

--Code Search (deprecated)

--Contacts

--Documents List

--Finance

--Health (deprecated)

--Maps (deprecated)

--Picasa Web Albums

--Spreadsheets

--Webmaster Tools

--YouTube

Comment: https://github.com/google/gdata-objectivec-client: "_This library should no longer be used for these APIs: Picasa Web Albums ([deprecated](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/deprecation); [migration info](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/developers_guide_migration))_"