# Issue setting up GData iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors, gdata

I am having trouble setting up my GData project for iPhone. I followed the instructions from the answer in the post [How to use GData in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543582/how-to-use-gdata-in-iphone). The project compiled fine but gives me a linker error if I try to run it. The linker error is

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataServiceGoogleYouTube", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in BWC_ViewController-C85FBF830F43777.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Please se the attached screenshot

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You claim the project compiles fine yet the output you posted clearly shows a whole bunch of compiler warnings. Warnings are bad. Fix them first.

Comment: The warnings were because I added header files in the compile sources in Build Phases. Removed them and the warnings are fixed now. But the linker error still persists.

Comment: Note that the GData API is not the current API for YouTube. Instead, apps should use the new JSON-based library, https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

Answer (score 0):

Usually your error means, that you are using GDataServiceGoogleYoutube in your BWC_ViewController without `#import "GDataServiceGoogleYoutube"` or some of GData `.m` files missing in your target. See following comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/14148008/2092007

Comment: The Gdata*.m files were missing from the target of my xcode project. They were present in the target of the GData project. However, as soon as I added them in the target, I am seeing ~200 odd warning messages like

    "warning: no rule to process file     '$(PROJECT_DIR)/TestYoutube/../../../trunk/Source/Introspection/GData    AtomCategoryGroup.m' of type file for architecture i386"

Answer (score 0):

Yes i got it.

this error because Gdata api use non arc and your project use arc.
 To avoid this two options are there

1. Go to project targets select the Build Phases tab go to Compile Sources find GDataServiceGoogleYoutube.m file and double click ,Type -fno-objc-arc.
2. change your project to non-arc (I recommend you to do the first option).

Note: You must change the all gdata classes to -fno-objc-arc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create runtime lib for deveice as well as simulator .

Get details in below Link
http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/